# Vim Substitution

Tags: vim, substitution

I always wanted to know, how you can substitute within given parameters.

If you have a line like this:

```
123,Hello,World,(I am, here), unknown
```

and you wnat to replace `World` with `Foobar` then this is an easy task: `:%s/World/Foobar/`

Now I wonder how I can get rid of a `,` which is wihtin the `( )`.

Theoretically I just have to find the first occurance of `(` then substitute the `,` with a blank until `)`.

Comment: Please read the FAQ entry about [formatting code blocks in your questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/151830)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try lookahead and lookbehind assertions:

```
%s/([^)]*\zs,\ze.*)//
```

(`\zs` and `\ze` tell where pattern starts and end)

or

```
%s/\(([^)]*\)\@<=,\(.*)\)\@=//
```

The first one is more readable, the second one uses `\( ... \)` groupings with parentheses inside groups which makes it look like obfuscated, and `\@<=` which apart from being a nice ASCII-art duck is the lookbehind operator, and `\@=` that is the lookahead operator.

References: `:help pattern` (more detail at `:help /\@=`, `:help /\ze`, etc.)

You use the GUI and want to try those commands? Copy them into the clipboard and run `:@+` inside Gvim.

Answer (score 3):

Modifying slightly the answer of @Tom can give you a quite good and "a bit" more readable result :

```
%s/\(.*\)(\(.*\),\(.*\))\(.*\)/\1(\2\3)\4/
```

That way you will have : in `\1` will store what is at the left outside of the parenthesis, `\4` what is at the right outside of the parenthesis and `\2` and `\3` what is inside the parenthesis, respectively on the left (`\2`) and on the right (`\3`).

With that you can easily swap your elements if your file is organised as column.

Comment: (by the way the Benoit's answer is far more elegant)

Comment: I was looking for something else, but I didn't know you could even do that! ... HERE, it's not clear just how you pull it off, but just knowing it can be done is a big help; if I ever need it, I'll dig into it further!

Answer (score 1):

You can also select the text you want to change (either with `visual` or `visual-block` modes) and enter the `:` to start the replace command. vi will automatically start the command with `:'<,'>` which applies the command to the selected area.

Replacing a `,` can be done with:

```
:'<,'>s/,/ /g
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example, this is the same thing as suggested by @ubuntuguy

```
%s/\(.*\)(\(.*\),\(.*\)/\1(\2\3
```

This will do the exact replacement you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will remove the last `, `, not the one inside `(` `)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach, based on the fact that actually you want to substitute only the first occurrence of `,` inside the parenthesis:

```
:%s#\((.\{-}\),#\1 #
```

Explanation:

- `:%s` for substitution in the whole file (don't use `%` if you want to work only with the current line)
- we can use `#` or `:` as a delimiter to make the command more readable
- in `(.\{-}` we ask to find any symbol (dot) after the left parenthesis and the rest stands for 0 or more occurrence (as few as possible) of this symbol. This expression is put inside `\(...\)` to be able to refer to this group as `\1` in the future.